# Increment the field by one in sqlite database android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a database with a table which represents Shop for my game.  The problem is, that when I use the method to purchase it doesn't increment the value by one but just sets it to zero. So how can I improve the method to increment the value of ItemNumberOfPurchases by one each time it's called for specific ID ? Here is my code for this.

```
public class MonsterTapDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
static final String dbName = "MonsterTapDb";
static final int version = 1;
static final String tTableName = "Shop";
static final String fItemID = "ItemID";
static final String fItemName = "ItemName";
static final String fItemNumberOfPurchases = "NumberOfPurchases";
static final String fItemIsLocked = "IsItemLocked";


public MonsterTapDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, dbName, null, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+tTableName+" (" +
            fItemID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " +
            fItemName + " TEXT , " +
            fItemNumberOfPurchases + " INT, " +
            fItemIsLocked + " TEXT" +
            ")");
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(fItemID, 1);
    cv.put(fItemName, "Lives");
    cv.put(fItemNumberOfPurchases, 0);
    cv.put(fItemIsLocked, "true");
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(tTableName, null, cv);
    cv.put(fItemID, 2);
    cv.put(fItemName, "Hardmode");
    cv.put(fItemNumberOfPurchases, 0);
    cv.put(fItemIsLocked, "true");
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(tTableName, null, cv);
    cv.put(fItemID, 3);
    cv.put(fItemName, "Reversed");
    cv.put(fItemNumberOfPurchases, 0);
    cv.put(fItemIsLocked, "true");
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(tTableName, null, cv);
    cv.put(fItemID, 4);
    cv.put(fItemName, "Reversed Hardmode");
    cv.put(fItemNumberOfPurchases, 0);
    cv.put(fItemIsLocked, "true");
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(tTableName, null, cv);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tTableName);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}
public void purchase(int ID){

    SQLiteDatabase myDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    myDB.execSQL("UPDATE " + tTableName+
            " SET "+fItemNumberOfPurchases+"=IFNULL("+fItemNumberOfPurchases+",0)+1"+
            " WHERE "+fItemID+"="+ID);
    myDB.close();

}
public void lockItem(int ID){
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(fItemIsLocked, false);
    myDB.update(tTableName, cv, fItemID+"=?", new String []{String.valueOf(ID)});
}
public String isPurchased(int ID){
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] mySearch = new String[]{String.valueOf(ID)};
    Cursor myCursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT "+ fItemIsLocked +" FROM "+ tTableName +" WHERE "+ fItemID +"=?",mySearch);
    myCursor.moveToFirst();
    int index = myCursor.getColumnIndex(fItemID);
    String myAnswer = myCursor.getString(index);
    myCursor.close();
    return myAnswer;
}
public int numberOfLives(){
    int ID = 1;
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] mySearch = new String[]{String.valueOf(ID)};
    Cursor myCursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT "+ fItemNumberOfPurchases +" FROM "+ tTableName +" WHERE "+ fItemID +"=?",mySearch);
    myCursor.moveToFirst();
    int index = myCursor.getColumnIndex(fItemNumberOfPurchases);
    myCursor.close();
    return index;
}
```

}

Comment: did you set primary key for the table ?

Comment: yes, the ID is the primary key. But I dont want to increment ID but the fItemNumberOfPurchases

Comment: You could have set the primary key as AUTOINCREMENT

Comment: Autoincrementing doesn't work too

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using `fItemNumberOfPurchases` instead of `fItemID`;
2. Why whould you compare a ID with a inequality?
3. If `fItemNumberOfPurchases` is `NULL`, arithmetic with numbers will always return `NULL`, which may be handled with [IFNULL](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull).

Corrected:

```
SQLiteDatabase myDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
myDB.execSQL("UPDATE " + tTableName+
    " SET "+fItemNumberOfPurchases+"=IFNULL("+fItemNumberOfPurchases+",0)+1"+
    " WHERE "+fItemID+"="+ID);
myDB.close();
```

Comment: this does not work. I want it to first set the number to 1 and then 2 and so on. But neither your nor mine code doesn't work

Comment: Probably you haven't initialized `fItemNumberOfPurchases`, so it is `NULL` and `NULL+1=NULL`. Using `CAST(... AS INTEGER)` will solve this.

Comment: still after update doesn't work. I basically used this myDB.execSQL() from another question, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Still not working. Hmm, can you suggest me another solution for this ? I have a table as described. I have a primary key called fItemID. and I want to increment the value of fItemNumberOFPurchases by one each time I execute this method.

Comment: I got cant open database exception. I will edit my question with full source code of my datagase class

Comment: Ok, you must fix DB opening issue first. Incrementing is not your problem, right now...

Comment: I'm not Android specialist. You'd better place another question regarding "open database exception" issue.